# Equivalent of System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding

Im trying to get all bytes from a file but the issue is that i only have access to the file once so what im doing is saving the file´s string in a txt file so when i need to use it i read the  saved file´s string and convert the string to a byte array but something is not working,
basicaly what i need is the equivalent of  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath) what is actually working good but is not what i need in this case.

i've tried this out so far

```
 public byte[] getByteArray(string fileString)
    {

        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.utf8;

        Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;

        Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;



        return utf8.GetBytes(fileString);

    }
```

i have tried every encoding of that class but didn't work

Comment: `is saving the file´s string in a txt file`... Do you mean making a copy of the file? Why can you not use `ReadAllBytes(filePath)`? Your question is very unclear as to what you actually need

Comment: Why not just copy the file? I don't see the reason for loading the binary file and then saving it as text into a new file. Just copy the file. Simple.

Comment: the file i read is a binary file so i read all the content of that file, then i put that content in a txt file to use it as many times as i need. and the file is expected to be stored in azure so before i put the file in azure i do what i mentioned before so because its stored in azure i cant use ReadAllBytes(filePath), i said that it´s working good when i test my code   with my file in the root´s  project but is not where it´s suppose to be

Comment: sorry for the previous comment it was incomplete